# What happened after fire finished burning?

Tags: gas-laws, combustion, temperature

After fire finished burning, did it merge with the atmosphere and becoming water vapors, oxygen and nitrogen, or did it simply disappear into nothing?

Comment: This is typical scenario for parallel accounts, when one of them is forbidden to ask new questions. That would be against the site policy.

Answer (score 3):

One thing is a flame as phenomena, other thing is matter involved in a flame.

A flame as phenomena just disappears. It is a state of gaseous matter at high temperature, when its gaseous and possibly small solid particles are emitting light. When the gas cools down enough, it stops emission and is not perceived as a flame anymore. The flame is  usually caused, but is not limited to, by exothermic combustion of gases or vapors in air or oxygen. ( Small flames over burning coke is combustion of gaseous carbon monoxide.)

The matter, that was forming the flame, mixes with air in the same way how it was mixing during fire when leaving a flame.

---

If matter mixes with air and if vapour, carbon dioxide, oxygen, nitrogen and minor components are matter then they mix with air.